# How to integrate java and hive in ubuntu?

Tags: java, sql-server, eclipse, hadoop, jdbc

I am new to hadoop. I am using ubuntu and have installed hadoop, hive and pig. I am trying to create a interface in java which gets hive query and executes it in background.

I am using IDE Eclipse -mars

Source code

```
    package com.soniya.demo2;


    import java.sql.SQLException;
    import java.sql.Connection;
    import java.sql.ResultSet;
    import java.sql.Statement;
    import java.sql.DriverManager;


    public class TestJdb
    {
      private static String driver = "org.hadoop.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver";

      /**
       * @param args
       * @throws SQLException
       */
      public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException {
          try {
          Class.forName(driver);
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
          System.exit(1);
        }

        Connection connect = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:hive2://:16074/default","","");
        Statement state = connect.createStatement();
        String tableName = "test";
        state.executeQuery("drop table " + tableName);
        ResultSet res = state.executeQuery("create table " + tableName + " (key int, value string)");

       // Query to show tables
        String show = "show tables";
        System.out.println("Running show");
        res = state.executeQuery(show);
        if (res.next()) {
          System.out.println(res.getString(1));
        }

        // Query to describe table
        String describe = "describe " + tableName;
        System.out.println("Running describe");
        res = state.executeQuery(describe);
        while (res.next()) {
          System.out.println(res.getString(1) + "\t" + res.getString(2));
        }

      }
    }
```

I am getting the following error

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hadoop.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
        at com.soniya.demo2.TestJdb.main(TestJdb.java:21)
```

Help me resolve this problem. 
I have included jar files like hive-jdbc,hadoop-common, but it din't work, also tried with hive lib jar files still getting same error. 
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Try to replace driverName "org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver" instead of "org.apache.hadoop.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver";